# change array with objects into new array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I have this array with objects,

```
[
    {
         "QuestionID":1350,
         "Answers":[
                {
                     "AnswerId":"1350_1",                    
                     "selected":true
                },
                {
                     "AnswerId":"1350_2",                    
                     "selected":false
                },
                {
                     "AnswerId":"1350_3",                    
                     "selected":false
                }
         ]
    },
    {
         "QuestionID":1349,
         "Answers":[
                {
                     "AnswerId":"1349_1",                    
                     "selected":false
                },
                {
                     "AnswerId":"1349_2",                    
                     "selected":true
                },
                {
                     "AnswerId":"1349_3",                    
                     "selected":false
                }
         ]
    }
]
```

but it should be changed to this, where answerID is the selected answers ID

```
[
    {
        "QuestionID": 1350, 
        "AnswerId": "1350_1"
    },
    {
        “QuestionID”: 1349, 
        “AnswerId”: "1349_2"
    }
]
```

Comment: What prevents you doing it?

Comment: Just a bad question with no explanation...

Comment: Post some code you tried

Comment: The second object in the expected output uses so-called ["smart quotes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Smart_quotes) that makes it look nice in MS Word but incorrect Javascript. No quotes are needed for property names if they are valid identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that:

```
data.map(item => ({
  QuestionID: item.QuestionID,
  AnswerId: item.Answers.find(answer => answer.selected).AnswerId,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr.map( s => (s.AnswerId = s.Answers.find( p => p.selected ).AnswerId, delete s.Answers, s) )
```

Explanation

- Use **map** to iterate
- Iterate answer for each question and **find** one with `selected == true`
- **Delete** the `answers` key

Demo

```js
var input = [{
    "QuestionID": 1350,
    "Answers": [{
        "AnswerId": "1350_1",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "AnswerId": "1350_2",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "AnswerId": "1350_3",
        "selected": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "QuestionID": 1349,
    "Answers": [{
        "AnswerId": "1349_1",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "AnswerId": "1349_2",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "AnswerId": "1349_3",
        "selected": false
      }
    ]
  }
];

var output = input.map(s => (s.AnswerId = s.Answers.find(p => p.selected).AnswerId, delete s.Answers, s));

console.log(output);
```